# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<x>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<y>'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, viewmodel, data-annotations

I've used data annotation in my View_Model layer and I have my entities in my Model Layer when I tried to get my methods from Model I got this error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List< DigikalaHR.Models.EF_Model.Member>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List< DigikalaHR.View_Model.Entitys.Member>'

this is my code in my View_Model layer where the error happened

```
    public Models.CRUD.Member Ref_CRUD { get; set; }

    public List<View_model.Entitys.Member> GetALLMembers()
    {
        Ref_CRUD = new Models.CRUD.Member();
        return (Ref_CRUD.Get_AllMemeberRecords());
    }
```

this is my code in my Model layer where I connect to my DB

```
    public List<EF_Model.Member> Get_AllMemeberRecords()
    {
        using (var context = new EF_Model.DigikalaHREntities())
        {
            var member = context.Members.OrderBy(i => i.Id).Select(i => i);
            return member.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use this code although you have change your model too

```
public IEnumerable<Entitys.Member> GetALLMembers()
    {
        IEnumerable<Models.EF_Model.Member> list = new Models.CRUD.Member().Get_AllMemeberRecords();
        List<Entitys.Member> listProduct = new List<Entitys.Member>();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            listProduct.Add(new Entitys.Member() { FirstName = item.FirstName,.....});
        }
        return listProduct;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception is saying just what it is wrong on your code. Why don´t you just do this?:

```
public Models.CRUD.Member Ref_CRUD { get; set; }

public List<EF_Model.Member> GetALLMembers()
{
    Ref_CRUD = new Models.CRUD.Member();
    return (Ref_CRUD.Get_AllMemeberRecords());
}
```

Comment: then how can I use my data annotation? How can I check those?

Comment: Put them on EF_Model.Member (?)

Comment: is there any way that I can use them in view model layer?

Comment: data annotations are the mapping from your BL objects to the database tables, they should not be required in the VM layer.